# Uploading song to Soundcloud account using javascript

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am trying to upload a song to soundcloud using the souncloud API and javascript. But I don't seem to be able to do it. This is my  javascript

```
function ADDTRACK() {
    var test = document.getElementById('SongTrack').files[0];
    SC.get("http://api.soundcloud.com/users/redstr/tracks.json?client_id=3200814596a029b47877e63edfe6066c", {
        limit: 1
    }, function(tracks) {
        SC.POST({
            tracks: {
                description: 'This track was recorded in Berlin',
                asset_data: '@' + test
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And this is my HTML upload

```
  <input type="file" id ="SongTrack" name="pic" accept="audio/*" />
      <button type="button"   onclick="ADDTRACK()" />Add TRACK</button>
```

I get no errors, so can anyone point me in what im doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the debugger? I'm not familiar with the API, but maybe there is a "onSucess" and "onError" even you can capture, like with the Jquery Ajax calls that you can capture to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

From: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#uploading

```
// the JavaScript SDK does not by itself have access
// to the filesystem, so instead this example records
// some audio in the browser and uploads it.

        SC.connect(function() {
          SC.record({
            start: function() {
              window.setTimeout(function() {
                SC.recordStop();
                SC.recordUpload({
                  track: { title: 'This is my sound' }
                });
              }, 5000);
            }
          }    
    });
```

So you can't directly upload the track with javascript.

Comment: It seems to me though that is out dated, Javascript can in theory get access to the files through the filesApi in html 5... I just made a direct uploader to Youtube using that, it would be great if I could achieve the same with SoundCloud...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up wanting to upload audio files via Javascript SDK as well, so I reverse engineered the PHP and JS SDKs to make it work.

First, you should make sure you have the Javascript SDK working.  We're only using it for the authentication token (using an undocumented method).  Aside from the token, the rest of it is handled manually using `$.ajax` and a `FormData` object.

HTML:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.8.3/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<button id="login">log in</button>
<form>
    <label>Title: <input name="title" disabled /></label><br>
    <label>File: <input name="file" type="file" accept="audio/*" disabled /></label><br>
    <button type="submit" disabled >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "INSERT_CLIENT_ID",
    redirect_uri: "INSERT_REDIRECT_URI"
});

$("#login").click(function(){
    SC.connect(function(){
        $('form input,form button').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});

$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('oauth_token', SC.accessToken());
    fd.append('format','json');
    fd.append("track[title]", $(this).find('input[name=title]').val());
    fd.append("track[asset_data]", $(this).find('input[name=file]').prop('files')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.soundcloud.com/v1/tracks',
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                if(e.lengthComputable) {
                    var percent = Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
                    console.log(percent  + '% uploaded');
                }
            };
            return xhr;
        }
    }).done(function(e) {
        console.log('Upload Complete!');
        console.dir(e); // This is the JSON object of the resulting track
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```